# Best Practices for SSH, tmux & GnuPG Agent

Tags: ssh, tmux, gpg

I'm attempting to consolidate my encryption software to GnuPG, and I'm running into a confusing problem.

My primary unit is a headless server, and I exclusively work in tmux. There is no X session, and therefore I've configured gpg-agent to use pinentry-curses. I've configured gpg-agent to be called on login with ssh-agent emulation with this script:

```
if pgrep -u "${USER}" gpg-agent >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval `cat $gnupginf`
    eval `cut -d= -f1 $gnupginf | xargs echo export`
else              
    eval `gpg-agent -s --enable-ssh-support --daemon`
fi
```

I've already added my ssh key to gpg-agent, however when I attempt another ssh session the command hangs.

I've discovered that if I kill gpg-agent and create a new login shell, the agent works as it should (calling pinentry-curses then working like ssh-agent).

If, however, I create another login shell (by, say, popping open another tmux pane) and attempt to ssh, the command hangs and the pinentry-curses window is printed over the contents of the login shell that originally launched the agent.

Further, if I've closed the shell that originally launched the agent, pinentry-curses is called anyway and causes a cpu-crippling infinite loop. (Known bug, see http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=559936.)

In essence, I'd like to know what to change about my setup to make GnuPG agent work as seamlessly as ssh-agent. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this one was incredibly simple. Instead of using that script, I simply removed the "--agents" option from my old keychain launch script (guide [here](http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain#Linux)).

This causes the Keychain program to seek out both ssh-agent AND gpg-agent files. Now my encryption system does work quite seamlessly, even while relying on both types of agents.